# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException in Processing 3/Java

Tags: java, processing

I am comparatively new on Processing 3.0 with no such background in Java. I am attempting to plot serial data from Arduino Uno.

- Error from category "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" in **com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException**.
- Sharing a screenshot of the whole thing here.
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6376715 -- this is the only related link I could find, which might contain solution but I do not understand it.

Other conversations on StackOverflow and other forums regarding this Exception thread do not majorly focus on "ObjectCollectedException".

Any help and suggestions on the matter will be appreciated. Many thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn9YI.png)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: You'll have to show us the relevant parts of the code to get any kind of meaningful answer. Also, please don't post screenshots of code or error messages. Just put the text of the code or error message right in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I will improve the question as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error as shown in the image says, there is an error in your VariableNode.java file on line 99. Since this is handled by Processing, the shown error is not helping us to find the bug.

As explained here [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectCollectedException.html), the ObjectCollectedException is thrown, when some action on an object is not possible because that object is already garbage collected (deleted).

In Java, any object that has no reference pointing to it is given free to the garbage collector ([Garbage Collector Explanation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)).

Without any source code, we are not able to find and help you with the error. 
Supplementary Processing often has its own error output, which shows you the line of error.

By inspection of the image, it looks like there is an error with a table cell and showing the data of that cell.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Your answer makes sense because:


-- I am using an array of length [2500] to store the incoming serial data (sampling rate 250Hz approx.).


-- 0th element of the array is updated everytime a new voltage value comes through signal generator via array shifting method. - all of this happens in serialevent().


-- Draw uses for loop to draw a line for each value (total 2500). Will  be posting a snippet of the code here in a while. 

Thanks again, appreciate your help.